# How to add a DialogFragment in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, baseadapter, dialogfragment

Hello I've looked around and haven't been able to find a clear answer for my problem.  I have a `custom adapter`, `BaseAdapter`, that I'm using in conjunction with my `ListActivity`.  Inside the view for each adapter item, I want to add a `checkbox` that, when `clicked`, starts a `dialog fragment` asking the user if they want to remove that item.  I am having trouble creating the `FragmentManager` from within the `BaseAdapter`.  Below is my code for the `getView` portion from `BaseAdapter` class.
Edit: Code is working fine now.  I ended up passing the `Activity` from the `Adapter`'s constructor and used that `Activity` to get the `FragmentManager`.

```
private ArrayList<AssignmentRecord> alist = new ArrayList<AssignmentRecord>();

private final Context aContext;

public AssignmentAdapter (Context context, Activity activity){
    aContext = context;
    aActivity = activity;
}


public void addItem (AssignmentRecord item) {
    alist.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteItem (AssignmentRecord item) {
    alist.remove(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    final CheckBox statusBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_finish_checkbox);
    if (assignmentRecord.getCurrentStatus()== AssignmentRecord.Status.NOTFINISHED){
        statusBox.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        statusBox.setChecked(true);
    }

    statusBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        class removeCheckedFragment extends DialogFragment{
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove this item?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                deleteItem(assignmentRecord);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                return builder.create();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                //prompt to delete record;

                assignmentRecord.setStatus(AssignmentRecord.Status.FINISHED);


                FragmentManager fragManager = aActivity.getFragmentManager();

                removeCheckedFragment newFragment = new removeCheckedFragment();
                newFragment.show(fragManager, "TEST");


                // cancel intent for alarm manager


            } else {
                // do nothing
            }

        }
    });

    return itemlayoutview;
}
```

I'm running into errors when trying creating the FragmentManager.  Specifically, I am getting this message

```
111-05 00:03:56.575    3839-3839/com.example.victor.listadapterexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at com.example.victor.listadapterexample.AssignmentAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(AssignmentAdapter.java:153)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:126)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So, it crashs at this line `FragmentManager fragManager = ((Activity)aContext).getFragmentManager();` ?

Comment: share full logcat error result

Comment: Dont instantiate the adapter with application context.

Comment: i've updated the logcat error.  It does crash at the line `FragmentManager fragManager = ((Activity)aContext).getFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eugen Pechanec states:

> Dont instantiate the adapter with application context.

I'll add a little context to this answer though so it makes more sense.

You're passing the `Application`'s `Context` to your `Adapter`. The issue is that you're trying to use this `Context` as replacement for your `Activity`. In most cases you'd probably be able to do this without any issues because both the `Activity` class and the `Application` class inherits from the `ContextWrapper` class.

In your case however, this won't work, because you're trying to use a method `getFragmentManager()` that belongs to the `Activity` class and not the `ContextWrapper` class.

There are multiple solutions for this issue:

1. Pass the `Activity`'s `Context` to the `Adapter` in the constructor.
2. Don't create and show the `DialogFragment` directly from your `Adapter`. Instead add a listener to your `Adapter` in the constructor and call that listener whenever you want to show the `DialogFragment`. The listener will reference a listener inside your `Activity`.

There are other solutions, but I believe the ones mentioned are the most common ones.

On a side-note: It is generally considered bad practice to use the `Application`'s `Context` in places like this as the scope of this `Context` is the whole app, and so your `Adapter` actually references everything in your app right now - this could cause memory leaks for instance.
Use as narrow a scope as possible. For instance if you only need a `Context`, you could also get that from `convertView` in your `getView()` method as all `View`s has a `Context`, but in a much more narrow scope.

Sorry for the long post and I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post.  So if I'm understanding this correctly, I need to pass the `Activity` from my ListActivity' to call `getFragmentManager()`.  I've already passed the `Activity`' s `Context` in the constructor, but I'm not sure how that gets an Activity instance to call `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Yes that's correct - pass the `Activity` as an argument in the constructor of the `Adapter` and not the `Context`. Then save the `Activity` as a global variable in your `Adapter` and use it whenever you need it in the `getView()`.